# Symfony2 Doctrine oneToMany orderBy multiple columns

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, yaml

I have code (.yml) like this:

```
oneToMany:
        products:
            targetEntity: SMS\Bundle\SwiadczeniaPlatne\Domain\Zlecenie\Produkt
            mappedBy: zlecenie
            cascade: [persist, remove]
            indexBy: id
            orphanRemoval: true
            orderBy: { patient: ASC, contract: ASC }
```

Patient and contract are objects. I want sort products by patient.name and contract.name. How can I do this?

Comment: I would only ever do it in the query.  Much more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

You have a wrong format:

```
oneToMany:
        products:
            targetEntity: SMS\Bundle\SwiadczeniaPlatne\Domain\Zlecenie\Produkt
            mappedBy: zlecenie
            cascade: [persist, remove]
            indexBy: id
            orphanRemoval: true
            orderBy: 
                patient: ASC
                contract: ASC
```

Bookmark this doctrine2 entity yaml reference gist: https://gist.github.com/mnapoli/3839501